# Ionic 4 Click event

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Hi I started learning Ionic 4. Currently my versions in packages.json are

```
      "@angular/animations": "~7.0.0",
      "@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
      "@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.2",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.2",
      "@angular/router": "^7.2.2",
      "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
      "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
      "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
      "@ionic/angular": "^4.0.0"
```

And am trying to use button as

```
<button ion-button (click)="test()">Click Me! </button>
```

The problem is that the click event is not binding. What am I missing here?

Comment: What do you mean by "not binding" ? What is inside your test function ? How do you test your code ?

Comment: Can you share your typescript file, please?

Comment: inside my test function just a console.log('string') line is there! and I found the answer that Ionic 4 doesn't support button tag. Check the answer by +Tomas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ionic 4 doesn't use the `<button>` tag anymore, but instead uses `<ion-button>`.

```html
<!-- Default -->
<ion-button>Default</ion-button>
```

Have a look here: https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/button